# Representation of a symmetric diagonal matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm

Lets assume we have a huge symmetric diagonal matrix. What is the efficient way to implement this?

The only way that i could think of is that by using the symmetric property where Xij = Xji, we can reduce the size of this matrix by half. But then representing this matrix using a 2D array would be inefficient, since we cant reduce the matrix size by using arrays.

Another thing representing this matrix using adjacency list also would be inefficient, because relating this matrix to a graph. It would be a density graph. And the operation of adj list takes lots of time such as removing, inserting and searching.

But what about using heaps?

Comment: Try a 1D array with a jagged column and indexing to handle the mirroring.

Comment: Yes thats a good option. Is there any other methods you can think of?

Comment: Not enough information to give you anything better, I'm afraid. Need to know your intended usage pattern, but 1D array even with the moderately complex indexing math you'd need hits a lot of sweet spots.

Comment: Emm.. What is symmetric diagonal matrix? Could you show an example?

Answer (score 3):

There is no one answer until you decide what you are going to do with this matrix (or maybe matrices?).

If you are just going to store and remember it, then just store it sequentially, leaving out the redundant entries.  (Your code knows how to access it, because that is all it does, right?)

More probably, you want to do normal matrix operations on it.  In that case, are you trying to make the storage efficient, or the execution?  In the later case, I don't see many opportunities based on it being symmetric--the multiplies are the expensive thing and you probably still need all of those.  If it is the storage, then are you limiting yourself to operations that only take symmetric in and symmetric out?  Sounds awfully specific.  If so, then you only need to do the calculations for the part you are storing, because, by definition the other entries are symmetric, so just write your code to generate that part of the matrix and you are done.

Comment: Sometimes u know we need to balance between efficient storage and efficient execution. The matrix that im dealing with it holds the distances between points i.e. Distance metric such as cosine distance. Since im dealing with larges data sets i need to find efficient data structure that will balance between storages and execution.

Comment: Usually saving in the range 0-50% doesn't get anyone too excited (it is the 90-99.9% saving that is a real payoff).  But if that makes your system feasible, I'd say it is worth writing all the code so it knows the shape of each matrix--it is only the operation code that gives meaning to any given location in the matrix anyway.